# Unable to connect to Mysql via JDBC but works fine with Mysql

Tags: mysql, jdbc

I have a mysql server running locally to which I am able to connect using

```
mysql -h localhost -u root
```

It does not require a password. But when I try to connect with the same attributes (jdbcurl = `"jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mysql"`, user = `root`) via JDBC, I get this weird exception

```
he last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490)
    at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:61)
    at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:105)
    at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:151)
    at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createCommunicationsException(ExceptionFactory.java:167)
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeSocketConnection.connect(NativeSocketConnection.java:91)
    at com.mysql.cj.NativeSession.connect(NativeSession.java:144)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:956)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:826)
    ... 33 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
    at java.base/java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:399)
    at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:242)
    at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:224)
    at java.base/java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:403)
    at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:591)
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.StandardSocketFactory.connect(StandardSocketFactory.java:155)
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeSocketConnection.connect(NativeSocketConnection.java:65)
    ... 36 more
```

What could be the issue here?

**EDIT**
Tried out the suggestion given in the comments to try to connect to mysql database via `mysql` as being done in java.

```
mysql -h localhost -u root mysql
```

This works and I get connected to the mysql db.

Comment: You  didn't connect with your mysql.exe connection to a database, but in java you told the connection that you want  to connect to the database mysql. instead of mysql use your own database and try tihs also in the command.

Comment: @nbk tried out your suggestion. I have updated the question with an EDIT

Comment: Please add the connection code with the connection string init

Comment: you might want to check the answers here as well https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6865538/solving-a-communications-link-failure-with-jdbc-and-mysql

Answer (score 1):

## Case 1 - JDBC connects as `root@127.0.0.1` but privilege is not granted:

It is possible that your `mysql` CLI is connecting via Unix domain socket (as `root@localhost`) while your Java application attempts to connect via TCP (as `root@127.0.0.1`) but privilege is not granted.

To verify, run `status` command in the mysql client:

```sh
mysql -h localhost -u root -e 'status'
```

The `Connection` field should show if you are connecting to `Localhost via UNIX socket` or `127.0.0.1 via TCP/IP`

If you are connecting via UNIX socket, you may try forcing the client to use TCP instead:

```sh
mysql -h localhost -u root --protocol TCP -e 'status'
```

If it fails, you may check if you have the user allowed from the host `127.0.0.1`:

```sql
SELECT * FROM mysql.user WHERE Host = '127.0.0.1'\G
```

An empty result set indicates that you don't have that user `root@127.0.0.1` yet. You may create it with:

```sql
CREATE USER 'root'@'127.0.0.1' IDENTIFIED BY '';
GRANT ALL ON *.* TO 'root'@'127.0.0.1' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

You may then retry the TCP and Java application.

## Case 2 - `localhost` translated to IPv6

If you have no problem connecting via TCP as described above, then another possibility is that the `localhost` string is translated by your Java application to the IPv6 `::1` while your MySQL server isn't configured to listen to the IPv6 interface.

You may try using `127.0.0.1` in your `jdbcurl`, e.g.: `jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/mysql`.

If for some reasons you cannot change `jdbcurl`, you may try launching your Java application with the `-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true` option, e.g.:

```sh
java -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -jar myapp.jar
```

Answer (score 0):

Which MySQL Version you are using ?

You won't be able to use root user I guess.

Create new application user and use that user for application.

```
CREATE USER appuser@'%' identified by 'PASSWORD';
Grant SELECT on *.* to appuser@'%';
flush privileges;
```